# How can I check the status of a stored proc invoked by user in oracle?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, exception

I want to know whether a particular stored proc invoked by a user in oracle has succeeded or failed?

In other words, if there is something like session or task log table which could come handy in some edge cases?

Edge cases being:

- proc has executed successfully
- or has not
- the proc gets hung
- the proc is being abruptly terminated
- or could be anything which I cannot really handle.

Comment: Assuming the procedure in question doesn't have an exception block that hides all errors, then it succeeds if it doesn't return an exception.

Comment: Got that but can I explicitly check the status of a fired proc by any user at any time ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "check the status of a fired proc by any user at any time" - you want to see some sort of log of executions and their outcome? If so, you'll have to add logging code to your procedures.

Comment: Giving access to users to run procedures, is really not a good thing.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal if that were the case, how would anything ever get run in the db?! Application users need to be able to run procedures, etc etc!

Comment: @Boneist by having an application layer over the procedures ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal but how is the application layer supposed to run the procedures? An application [layer] that logs into the database connects as a user, and if it needs to run stored procs, it has to have the necessary privs to do so.

Comment: @Boneist - Yes agreed, but the logging is something we should be taking care of by the application and not the database. Simply because application is User aware, not the database.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal If you mean that database code shouldn't ever have logging in it then I disagree with you. Well instrumented code (whichever layer it is) is code that makes it easy to debug issues etc. If you're saying that the application should be the only thing logging whether the procedure was successful or not, I sort of half agree with you. Yes, it should be logging it, if that's what will provide the info the OP is after, but that doesn't preclude separate logging in the database code.

Comment: @Boneist thanks for the logging suggestion but the use case that I have is something like this: I want to know whether my proc has executed successfully or not including the error scenarios like the proc gets hung or is being abruptly terminated or could be anything which I cannot really handle.

Comment: It entirely depends on your procedure. Like I said earlier, if a procedure doesn't return an exception, then it's counted as successful. This assumes that your procedure isn't hiding exceptions. So, if you run a procedure and you get an exception returned, then you know it's "failed". If you don't, then it's succeeded. If a procedure is abruptly terminated, you will usually get some sort of exception returned. If it's taking a long time... well, you'll have to have something else monitoring for that.

Comment: yeah sure, just was thinking if there is something like session or task log table which could come handy in those edge cases then it would have been great but thanks anyway!

Comment: If you want to track the status of Procedure, you can run that procedure using Oracle scheduler job. and after that you can easily track the status of procedure from User_scheduler_job_run_details table.